# multiple subdomain redirects to urls in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to have multiple subdomains to point to their dedicated url.

for example: 
johndoe.mysite.com will point to mysite.com/user/johndoe/
janedoe.mysite.com will point to mysite.com/user/janedoe/ or mystic.com/user/abc/ (if multiple same names)
and so on.

no problem with creating the subdomains through cpanel.

need some help with writing the htaccess that can take care of this.
from searching i got the code below to work on a single redirect.
how can it be modified for the scenario above?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^johndoe.mysite.com $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/user/johndoe/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

thanks in advance. also i'd like to state that this is my first time working on htaccess so if the question is "dense" i apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/user/%1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```